# Getting the first paragraph from a URL which doesn't contain script tags and it has words number > 20

Tags: php

I want to grab from a URL  the first paragraph which doesn't contain script tags and its words number is greater than 20. The right paragraph could be the 3rd one for example. Can you help me with that guys? I have made something like that until now.

```
 $start = strpos($url, '<p>');
 $end = strpos($url, '</p>', $start);
 $par1 = substr($url, $start, $end - $start + 4);   
 $count = str_word_count($par1);
 if ($count > 20) {     
     $par = html_entity_decode(strip_tags($par1));
     echo $par;
 }
```

This code is not exactly right. It shows the first paragraph in the URL, only if it has number of `words > 20`.

Comment: Is jQuery an option for this, or do you require it in PHP?

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian:I grab URLS and i want to grab the first paragraph from them which meets my two conditions.

Comment: @lethalMango: Yeah, jquery is an option too.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just average the desired string length (for instance 20 words is for example about 80 characters, in which case you could use this in XPATH: `//w[not(script) and string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 80]`

Comment: because i am not familiar with xpath, have i to use xpath with dom together??

Comment: In PHP: DOM, or SimpleXML. In javascript there are also methods, but they vary per browser, so you may want to use a library for that.

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate through all of the p tags with the code you posted above. I think that's what you're looking for:

```
//You may want to rename $url if it contains your paragraphs.
$contents = explode("<p>", $url);

foreach($contents as $p)
{
     $end = strpos($p, '</p>', 0);
     $p = substr($p, 0, $end); // this will remove everything not in a <p>
     $p = strip_tags($p);
     if(str_word_count($p) > 20)
     {
         echo html_entity_decode($p);
     }
}
```

Comment: I test it buddy!!But there is a problem!!!From urls it grabs the content of <script> tags and show them as part of the original paragraphs.Do you know how can i remove the content of the script tags?? Moreover, all paragraphs are shown and not only the first one that meets the conditions.